# Spring data jpa named-native-query xml mapping

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to use named-native-query in xml 
It's my code and error

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="web.domain"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties"> 
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>                   
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>                 
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>           
                <prop key="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings">true</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>             
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
            <list>
              <bean class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
                <constructor-arg value="web" />
                <property name="mappingFileNamePattern" value="**/xml/*.xml" />
              </bean>
            </list>
          </property>
    </bean>
```

boardNative.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">
        <named-native-query name="selectTestQuery">
        <query>
            SELECT * FROM BOARD
        </query>
    </named-native-query>
```

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\hoyeon\git\jpa\web\target\classes\web\spring\context\context-jpa.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to resolve named mapping-file [web/target/classes/web/board/xml/boardNative.xml]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.__refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to resolve named mapping-file [web/target/classes/web/board/xml/boardNative.xml]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1245)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildMappingFileDescriptor(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildDeploymentResources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:222)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:188)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider$1.(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.__createEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:49)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 22 more
```

help me...

If I get solve I try this code

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
 private EntityManager em;

 em.createNamedQuery("selectTestQuery");
```

So to use that right?

thanks you!

I am not good at English .. sorry

Comment: the problem is clearly stated in the error message: `Unable to resolve named mapping-file [web/target/classes/web/board/xml/boardNative.xml]` .  You should be aware that `.../target/classes/...` is simply the build output directory of maven.  In the final artifact, the path relative to root of artifact should be something like `/web/board/xml/boardNative.xml` or `/WEB-INF/classes/web/board/xml/boardNative.xml`

Comment: I change my code like this <property name="mappingFileNamePattern" value="/WEB-INF/classes/web/board/xml/boardNative.xml" /> . but i get a new error     No query defined for that name [selectTestQuery]  T T  thanks you